# Adjusted survival curve based on weigthed cox regression

Tags: r

I'm trying to make an adjusted survival curve based on a weighted cox regression performed on a case cohort data set in R, but unfortunately, I can't make it work. I was therefore hoping that some of you may be able to figure it out why it isn't working.

In order to illustrate the problem, I have used (and adjusted a bit) the example from the "Package 'survival'" document, which means im working with:

```
data("nwtco")

subcoh <- nwtco$in.subcohort
selccoh <- with(nwtco, rel==1|subcoh==1)
ccoh.data <- nwtco[selccoh,]
ccoh.data$subcohort <- subcoh[selccoh]
ccoh.data$age <- ccoh.data$age/12 # Age in years

fit.ccSP <- cch(Surv(edrel, rel) ~ stage + histol + age, 
                data =ccoh.data,subcoh = ~subcohort, id=~seqno, cohort.size=4028, method="LinYing")
```

The data set is looking like this:

```
   seqno instit histol stage study rel edrel      age in.subcohort subcohort
4      4      2      1     4     3   0  6200 2.333333         TRUE      TRUE
7      7      1      1     4     3   1   324 3.750000        FALSE     FALSE
11    11      1      2     2     3   0  5570 2.000000         TRUE      TRUE
14    14      1      1     2     3   0  5942 1.583333         TRUE      TRUE
17    17      1      1     2     3   1   960 7.166667        FALSE     FALSE
22    22      1      1     2     3   1    93 2.666667        FALSE     FALSE
```

Then, I'm trying to illustrate the effect of `stage` in an adjusted survival curve, using the `ggadjustedcurves`-function from the survminer package:

```
library(suvminer)
ggadjustedcurves(fit.ccSP, variable = ccoh.data$stage, data = ccoh.data)
#Error in survexp(as.formula(paste("~", variable)), data = ndata, ratetable = fit) : 
#  Invalid rate table
```

But unfortunately, this is not working. Can anyone figure out why? And can this somehow be fixed or done in another way?

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to graphically illustrate the effect of a continuous variable in a weighted cox regression performed on a case cohort data set, so I would, generally, also be interested in hearing if there are other alternatives than the adjusted survival curves?

Comment: Hi! Well posed example, but it's not clear what you mean by "this is not working." Is there an error or are you unsatisfied with the results? btw: you asked a second question which is more of a statistics question than a programming question. The forum for stats questions is Cross Validated.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying and for the info about Cross Validated :-) When I enter the command, I get the error: ```[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected ```

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons it is throwing errors.

1. The `ggadjcurves` function is not being given a `coxph.object`, which it's halp page indicated was the designed first object.
2. The specification of the `variable` argument is incorrect. The correct method of specifying a column is with a length-1 character vector that matches one of the names in the formula. You gave it a vector whose value was a vector of length 1154.

This code succeeds:

```
 fit.ccSP <- coxph(Surv(edrel, rel) ~ stage + histol + age, 
                 data =ccoh.data)
 ggadjustedcurves(fit.ccSP, variable = 'stage', data = ccoh.data)
```

[image]

It might not answer your desires,  but it does answer the "why-error" part of your question. You might want to review the methods used by Therneau,  Cynthia S Crowson, and Elizabeth J Atkinson in their paper on adjusted curves:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/adjcurve.pdf

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it would work with any survival object. Thanks for explaining it and for the link!